# タスクスケジューラに設定したバッチファイルが実行されない

Tags: windows

バッチファイルからpythonを実行しようとしていますが、タスクスケジューラーからスケジュールを設定しても開示時刻になってもバッチからpythonが実行されません。

バッチファイルとpythonファイルは、同じフォルダに設置しています。
タスクスケジューラーから手動で実行すると、pythonは実行されます。

```
@echo off
python.exe C:\work\Script\actual\subpro.py
python.exe C:\work\Script\actual\Speed-test.py
```

原因がわかる方、ご教示下さい。

Comment: その「タスクスケジューラーからスケジュールを設定」した内容がどんなものか質問に詳細が記述されていないと @sayuri さん回答のように回答に対して追加情報が増えていくやり取りが続いてなかなか解決にはつながらない可能性が高いですよ。[【Windows 10対応】タスクスケジューラで定期的な作業を自動化する](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/1305/31/news049.html), [【Windows/タスクスケジューラ】バッチを実行する際の3つの注意点](https://www.teamxeppet.com/windows-taskschd/), [タスクスケジューラに登録したバッチがうまく実行できない時に確認すること](http://sogohiroaki.sblo.jp/article/178281845.html)

Comment: タスクスケジューラーの履歴を確認したところ、「起動要求が無視されました。インスタンスは既に実行中です」というメッセージがありました。対処方法を調べたところ、タスクスケジューラの該当のタスクのプロパティー→設定の「タスクが既に実行中の場合に適用される規則」にて「新しいインスタンスを並列で実行」を選択することで、指定した時間に起動できました。

Comment: 本件、色々調べたところ、タスクスケジューラーの設定ではなく、pythonファイルを2つ同時に実行しようとしており、プロセスが競合してしまっているようでした。バッチファイルからpythonファイルを起動（実行するのではなく）2つのpythonファイルを1つのファイルに統合し、同じプロセスで実行するようにしようと思います。本件は、一旦Closeとさせていただきます。参考サイトありがとございました。

Answer (score 1):

バッチ自身が実行できていないのか、それともバッチは実行されたが`python.exe`が見つけられずに結果的に実行されなかったのか、切り分けるべきです。

前者であれば、Pythonは関係ありません。設定を見直してください。

後者であれば、例えば環境変数`PATH`を確認してください。`PATH`が通っていないために`python.exe`を見つけられないだけの可能性があります。

---

バッチもPythonも関係なく、そもそも実行できていなかったとのこと。設定を見直し、実行できるようにしたとのこと。

> タスクスケジューラーの履歴を確認したところ、「起動要求が無視されました。インスタンスは既に実行中です」というメッセージがありました。対処方法を調べたところ、タスクスケジューラの該当のタスクのプロパティー→設定の「タスクが既に実行中の場合に適用される規則」にて「新しいインスタンスを並列で実行」を選択することで、指定した時間に起動できました。

Comment: PATHですが、pythonのPATHは通っています。```C:\Users\xxx_x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\xxx_x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;```