# タスクスケジューラから PowerShell を起動しても意図した通り実行されない

Tags: windows, powershell

タスクスケジューラのスクリプトにpowershell.exeまでのパスを書き、実行ファイルは `-Command '.¥"ファイル名"'` 、開始(オプション)を実行ファイルのあるディレクトリまでのパスを書いて実行したところ、powershellが一瞬開いてすぐに閉じてしまいます。状態は実行中のままですが、スクリプトは実行されていないようです。

このようにpowershellは一瞬開くが、すぐに閉じてしまい、スクリプトも実行されていないような場合、どのようなエラーが考えられますか。

なお、自分でpowershellを開いて、そのスクリプトは実行したので、実行ファイルのスクリプトが間違っていることはございません。また、pythonファイルのタスクスケジューラの設定、実行はできているので、powershell.exeの問題の可能性が高いです。

Comment: イベントログには何か出力されていませんか？

Comment: この辺の記事を参考に状況の詳細を追記したりログを採取して調べたりしてください。[バッチファイルからpython実行](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/80759/26370), [Windowsのタスクスケジューラで実行されたタスクの履歴を確認したいが、履歴が無効となっている。【Windows】](https://anything-it.info/eventvwr-exec-history/), [ログではpythonからメール送信(Outlook)できているが実際には送信されていない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/67216/26370)

Comment: powershell.exe に `-NoExit` を付けて実行してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 手動実行時とタスクスケジューラ実行時のカレントディレクトリが異なっているというのが一番単純に考えられるのではないでしょうか？スクリプト内に何らかのアウトプットを出せるようにして追いかけてはいかがでしょう？まずは実行時カレントを表示させるようにして違いを確かめてみては？

Comment: タスクスケジューラで実行できない場合に最初に確認すべきなのは、実行ユーザーとカレントディレクトリです。操作の設定にある「開始（オプション）」で、実行時のカレントディレクトリを指定できます。スクリプトを置いているディレクトリを指定するのが一般的です。

Comment: -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned を付けて実行してみたらどうでしょう？

Comment: 「開始（オプション）」をダブルクォーテーションで囲っているとか？ [PowerShellスクリプトをタスクスケジューラで実行する設定](https://saborin.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/08/07/000000), [WindowsのタスクスケジューラーでPowerShellのスクリプトを実行する際には「パス」に注意](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/1412/03/news125.html), [タスクスケジューラに登録したバッチがうまく実行できない時に確認すること](http://sogohiroaki.sblo.jp/article/178281845.html), [タスク スケジューラ で、空白を含む引数を指定すると (0x1) で終了してしまいます （CmdletBindingを使用した場合）](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/2ff58364-eadf-4f31-861e-e4ef874a648f)