# バッチからpowershellを起動すると、一瞬だけ開いてすぐに閉じてしまう

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

1 .batファイルを定期実行

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "Start-Process PowerShell.exe -Verb runas C:\*****\*****\*****.ps1"
```

2 .ps1が起動し、管理者権限で処理を実行する

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole("Administrators")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
--以下、実行スクリプト
```

2の段階で、psが管理者権限で開くところまでは確認できるのですが、その後一瞬で画面が閉じて後続の処理が実行されないです。
権限はあります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一瞬で閉じてしまうため何が原因なのか特定が難しいです。
調べ方が悪いのか、解決策が出てきません。
何かわかる方がいましたらヒントを教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: batファイルのコマンド全体を`powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted C:\*****\*****\*****.ps1`に書き換えて「管理者として実行」してもウィンドウは一瞬で消えますか？

Comment: 回答が付いておらず解決していませんが、こちらの記事と似ている状況ですね。[タスクスケジューラから PowerShell を起動しても意図した通り実行されない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/80973/26370) `1 .batファイルを定期実行`していることの詳しい状況が追記されると何か進展があるかもしれません。

Comment: PS1スクリプト単独では成功しているのでしょうか？その時とバッチファイルからの起動時にカレントが違っていないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントいただいた方、ありがとうございました。
原因はbatからps1を呼び出す際のパスが文字化けしていたことでした。
ユーザを変更することで解決することができました。